# Read variables from template in Django or Jinja2

Tags: django, templates, jinja2

Looking for a solution to read the complete list of variables that can be passed into a context and displayed within a template, using either Django or Jinja2.

For example, something like this in Django:

```
from django.template import Template

template = Template("<h1>{{title}}</h1>{%for v in values%}<p>{{v}}</p>{%endfor%}")
for node in template.nodelist:
    #Get the variable name from the node
```

This seems like a real pain. All I want is a list of the keys that a context object could pass to the template, in this example, "title" and "values"

Answer (score 2):

You could use {% debug %} tag

> debug
>
> Outputs a whole load of debugging information, including the current
>   context and imported modules.

Also if you want even more you could use [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar)

Comment: This isn't exactly what I am looking for. I am trying to read the template itself, using Python, and figure out what variables the template can take.

Comment: What template can take is called context

Comment: I know, but I am interested to know, without looking at the template code, what variables I can put into the context and have them rendered into the context.